# How to add managed GSuite account with mail disabled to iOS 12.0?

Tags: ios, accounts, google

I'm at a university with a centrally-managed GSuite account. They've disabled Mail there (we're using Office365 for that) but the Calendar function does work. I'm trying to add my calendar account to iOS. What I do:

1. Go Settings -> Passwords & Accounts -> Add Account -> Google
2. Enter my university email address
3. It shows a custom logon screen; I enter credentials
4. I get "Login successful, redirecting..."
5. I see the screen with switches for Mail, Contacts, Calendars, Notes, and a spinner at the top of the screen
6. I get redirected back to the "Add Account" screen, with iCloud, Exchange, and so on listed

I don't get an error message or anything, it just bumps me back.

Anyone know how I might make this work, or if there's even some sort of logging I could see?

For what it's worth, this works fine on MacOS.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same situation and problem. I contacted Apple Support today, they stated that they are **aware** of this issue and working together with Google to sort things out, they said it is a problem on the Google side.

I am going to **contact G Suite support** (I am an organisation admin) and will put the information provided by Google **in this post**.